# `quote_string: no implicit conversion from nil to integer` with datamapper on sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I have a simple Sinatra app and I'm trying to hook up DataMapper with the mysql adapter. The relevant part of the code looks like this

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'])

class Category
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,         Serial
  property :name,       String
end

DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!
```

I've double checked everything. I'm using Sinatra's modular pattern. I have `require 'data_mapper'` at the top of the module. Mysql server is up and running. But whenever I `rackup`, I get the following error:

`` Warning: Command failed: /dev/app/.bundle/gems/data_objects-0.10.14/lib/data_objects/quoting.rb:12:in `quote_string': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError) ``

I've search high and low for an answer, but the only thing I could find was one person suggesting a ruby upgrade from 2.0 to 2.1. I can't do that since this is being deploy to Openshift, where the highest ruby is 2.0. Any other suggestions on why this might be happening?

EDIT: forgot to add that the `DATABASE_URL` is populating fine, and I've also installed the `dm-mysql-adapter`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing rbenv on openshift and upgrading to 2.1+ ruby. See here for [more info](https://github.com/Seppone/openshift-rbenv-installer).